# Building Azure IoT Gateway SDK Solution with CMake Utility

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, cmake, iot, gateway

## I'm trying to build a sample Azure IoT Gateway SDK project with CMake 3.71 utility for Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 platform. When I tried to build the project both in VS2015 Command Line and CMake GUI, respectively, I got the following error log:

```
Determining if the _M_AMD64 exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/nanos/Documents/GitHub/project/azure-iot-gateway-sdk/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_23e97.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 12/6/2016 1:53:03 AM.

Project "C:\Users\nanos\Documents\GitHub\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_23e97.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTC_23e97.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "C:\Users\nanos\Documents\GitHub\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

  Creating directory "cmTC_23e97.dir\Debug\cmTC_23e97.tlog\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTC_23e97.dir\Debug\cmTC_23e97.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_23e97.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_23e97.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\nanos\Documents\GitHub\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckSymbolExists.c"

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_23e97.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_23e97.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\nanos\Documents\GitHub\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckSymbolExists.c"



  CheckSymbolExists.c

C:\Users\nanos\Documents\GitHub\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckSymbolExists.c(7): error C2065: '_M_AMD64': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\nanos\Documents\GitHub\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_23e97.vcxproj]

Done Building Project "C:\Users\nanos\Documents\GitHub\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_23e97.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.



Build FAILED.



"C:\Users\nanos\Documents\GitHub\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_23e97.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

(ClCompile target) -> 

  C:\Users\nanos\Documents\GitHub\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckSymbolExists.c(7): error C2065: '_M_AMD64': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\nanos\Documents\GitHub\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_23e97.vcxproj]



    0 Warning(s)

    1 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.65


File C:/Users/nanos/Documents/GitHub/project/azure-iot-gateway-sdk/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef _M_AMD64
  return ((int*)(&_M_AMD64))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}
```

=========================================================================

[Output from the CMake GUI here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzTNN.png)

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or guide me? I have spent significant amount of hours trying to figure out how to solve the issue. I have extensively searched for solutions online, but to no success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: Thanks, Rita. I used the following tutorial as my guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-windows-gateway-sdk-simulated-device

Comment: What about printed content in command window. Have you saw **"100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 16"** after the build completed?

Comment: The build in my situation when ran on the command window is incomplete and terminated with errors as recorded in the log file. In other words, the tests failed : -- Looking for InitializeConditionVariable - found
-- Performing Test NN_HAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS
-- Performing Test NN_HAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS - Failed
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:246 (message):

Comment: Thanks for the observation. Do you mean I should clone the repo "/azure-iot-gateway-sdk/" into a local directory that is on the root of C:\ ? Example: C:\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk. Right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related with this [note](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-gateway-sdk/blob/master/doc/devbox_setup.md):

> Note: Make sure to clone the repo into a directory heirachy with less
>   than 20 characters (if the path is prefix\azure-iot-gateway-sdk,
>   prefix must be less than 20 characters). Windows has limitations on
>   the length of file names and placing the repo in a hierarchy deeper
>   than 20 characters will cause the build to fail. Our build.cmd script
>   throws an error if it would eventually hit this failure, but one can
>   hit this when manually building the project with cmake.

I kill the "project" in the directory(...Documents/GitHub/project/azure-iot-gateway-sdk/...), then it works.

So, you need shorten the length of the directory that you clone the repo into.

Comment: Thanks for the observation. Do you mean I should clone the repo "/azure-iot-gateway-sdk/" into a local directory that is on the root of C:\ ? Example: C:\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk. Right?

Comment: @KKUser  Feel free to try to put the repo into  "C:\project\azure-iot-gateway-sdk". But my point is to keep store path of the repo short enough and your "C:\Users\nanos\Documents\GitHub\project\" maybe too long for it. The directory don't have to be the root of C:\.

Comment: Another issue is in running the build IoT solution. I have the following errors: failed to open the connection with CBS and AMQP transport failed to establish connection with the service, respectively. Please did you try to run the solution?

Comment: @KKUser I ran the solution and it worked for me. You may has some mistake with the JSON config file. You can reference this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-gateway-sdk/issues/68).